# add rows even if columns mismatch

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel sheet, loaded into a DataFrame, whose `tail()` looks like this

```
ix     date   Type    Value1  Value2  Value3
-------------------------------------------
651 01.02.2021  A    105       135    81
652 01.02.2021  B      3        10     1
653 01.02.2021  C    108       145    82
```

I have another DataFrame that instead look like this

```
0          02.02.2021   02.02.2021  02.02.2021
1              A            B           C
Value1        110           4          114
Val2          142          15          157
Value3         96           2           98
```

I want to add this latter dataframe transposed at the end of the first.

I have tried both `append()` and `pd.concat` but since column names do not always match (`Value2 != Val2`), values in the resulting columns end up being `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first dataframe is df1 and the second is df2:

First transpose df2 and reset the index:

```
df3 = df2.T.reset_index()
```

If the dataframe df2 is always of the same form, you can simply overwrite the column names:

```
df3.columns = df1.columns
```

And then concat:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df3],axis=0)
```

If the order of df2 is not always in the same and the misspellings can be different, you'll have to identify all possible misspellings first and for instance keep them in a dictionary like so:

```
mapping = {"Value1":"Value1","Value2":"Value2","Value3":"Value3","Val2":"Value2"}
```

Then assuming the value strings are in the index of df2, you overwrite the index:

```
df2.index = df2.index.map(mapping )
```

Afterwards you can perform the steps described above.

Comment: thanks! I've used your first suggestion, as mapping would become a tedious manual operation that is prone to many, many typos.